# Set notification at specific date in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, date, notifications, alert

I'm doing a project in which I have a list of food like a virtual fridge. You can insert dishes based on a main ingredient and I want the app to notify the user when the dish is gonna expire. I have an array of main ingredients and I want to create an array of dates for each one, in this way if you select "Chicken" as a main ingredient the expire date is 5 days from the insertion, for example.

Which is the simplest way to do this in order to alert users for each dish they have in the application? I don't know if it's important but I'm using Room to store the dishes in a list. I want two notifications for each dish, one for reminder 2 days before the expire date and other one the day before the expire date. I'm not familiar with notifications in Android so I appreciate so much the easiest way to understand how to do it.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use the **AlarmManager** to schedule the notification.

Comment: But can I have for example 10 notifications scheduled for different dates at the same time? Do I have to store them in a DB or similar?

Comment: For a reference, you can check this blog https://droidmentor.com/schedule-notifications-using-alarmmanager/